# Kahn algorithm & reachability

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, core-data, graph, visual-programming

For learning purpose I'm developping an application that in real life would work basically like [Quartz Composer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Composer) or the recent [Vuo](http://www.vuo.org/).
I'm building the graph of nodes on a Core Data Framework basis.

Basically I have a *Node* entity with a to-many relationship with *Input* and *Output* entities (a node can have multiple inputs and multiple outputs). *Input* has a to-one relationship to a *Connection* entity, while *Output* has a to-many relationship with the latter (an input can have only one connection, while an output can have many).

To read the graph I'm using a Topological Sorting algorithm (Kahn's one), described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The code is as follows :

```
/**
 * Get all nodes.
 */
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Node"];
NSMutableArray *nodes = [[[_document managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
/**
 * Reset the nodes 'visited' flag.
 */
[self reset:nodes];
/**
 * Get sources: predicate for nodes without input ports or with input ports without connections.
 */
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inputs == nil OR ALL inputs.connection == nil"]];
NSMutableArray *sources = [[[_document managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
/**
 * Perform a topological sort.
 */
while ([sources count] > 0) {
    /**
     * While there are sources.
     */
    NSManagedObject *node = [sources lastObject];
    /**
     * Add the node to the tail of the final graph (NSMutableArray).
     */
    [_graph addObject:node];
    [node setValue:@([_graph count] - 1) forKey:@"kNodeExecutionIndex"];
    [sources removeLastObject];
    /**
     * Outputs.
     */
    NSMutableSet *outputs = [node valueForKey:@"outputs"];
    for (NSManagedObject *output in outputs) {
        /**
         * Get output connections.
         */
        NSMutableSet *connections = [output valueForKey:@"connections"];
        for (NSManagedObject *connection in connections) {
            /**
             * Set the connection as already visited.
             */
            [connection setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"kConnectionVisited"];
            NSManagedObject *n = [[connection valueForKey:@"destination"] valueForKey:@"node"];
            /**
             * Set the 'source' flag to YES by default.
             */
            BOOL isNewSource = YES;
            /**
             * Get connected inputs.
             */
            NSMutableSet *inputs = [n valueForKey:@"inputs"];
            for (NSManagedObject *input in inputs) {
                /**
                 * Check if one of the input connections was visited.
                 * If not, then we need to process this connection and
                 * don't add it to sources for next pass.
                 */
                if ([[[input valueForKey:@"connection"] valueForKey:@"kConnectionVisited"] isEqualTo:@(NO)]) {
                    isNewSource = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isNewSource) {
                [sources addObject:n];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand the logic of how (and where in this code) I'd have to compute reachability for each Node (therefore for each Input) entity, if it is possible.

My questions are :

- Is it possible to compute the reachability of nodes inside the Kahn's algorithm ?
- If appropriate, where and how to do it, so I can understand why it is working ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at your code, I suggest to first create a subclass of the NSManagedObjects you create (node etc) so you can write simple code to access the relationships you created. This will make the code more maintainable.

In general, I am not sure I understand the question. You can follow the relationships  to test reachability of any managed object/node. This really has nothing to do with core data though.

Comment: Thank you, but Core Data isn't really the point here. I'd really like to know if we can adjust the Kahn's algorithm to get nodes reachability.

Comment: then you should remove the core-data & objective-c tags from this question

Comment: I saw I have the power to remove them so I did so. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, this HAS to do with CoreData and is written in Objective-C, the tags are pertinent.

Comment: OK, then I don't get it I guess